# Computer Guess my number C Programing

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code. I'm trying to create a game where the computer guesses the number that I input. Here is my code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

int numberGuess = 0;
int low = 1;
int high = 100;
int computerGuess = 0;

printf("Enter a number, 1 - 100: ");
scanf("%d", &numberGuess);

while (computerGuess != numberGuess) 
{

  computerGuess = ((high - low) + low)/2;
  printf("%d ", computerGuess);

  if (numberGuess > computerGuess)
    {
    printf("Your guess was to low \n");
    low = computerGuess+1;
    }
  else if (numberGuess < computerGuess)
    {
    printf("Your guess was to high \n");
    high = computerGuess-1;
}
  else if (numberGuess == computerGuess)
{
printf("Yess!! you got it!\n");
    }
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you start by telling us what works differently than you expect it to?

Comment: First off, your computer guess is the same every time, you should make it randomized and declare it before the start of the while loop.

Comment: Insert printf statements in your code to track what it's doing, and figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: FYI `computerGuess = ((high - low) + low)/2;` is exactly the same as `computerGuess = `high/2;`

Comment: @ryrich - The computer is trying to guess the number the user selects, not the user trying the guess the number the computer selects

Comment: This looks close to correct.  Debug time I think.  Notice what happens on the second time through with the computer guess assignment line it needs a slight adjustment to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

this line:

```
computerGuess = ((high - low) + low)/2;
```

should be:

```
computerGuess = (high - low)/2+low;
```

What you are looking for is the number half way between your high and low (this is a binary search, but I'm sure you knew that).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I guess I was just to tired to see that small mistake... Thanks

Comment: @user2133160 been there...sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

```
computerGuess = ((high - low) + low)/2;
```

Here you just add low and then imidiately substract it thus making the code equal

```
computerGuess = ((high)/2;
```

and you always compare the same value the while loop never ends.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (indeed, I made the same comment a moment ago).

Comment: @EricJ. Hmm...? sorry didn't see your comment. I actually ran the code and found the inf loop myself. :S

Comment: Well, with the edit it becomes an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Fix code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

int numberGuess = 0;
int low = 1;
int high = 100;
int computerGuess = 0;

printf("Enter a number, 1 - 100: ");
scanf("%d", &numberGuess);

while (computerGuess != numberGuess) 
{

  computerGuess = ((high - low)/2 + low);
  printf("%d ", computerGuess);

  if (numberGuess > computerGuess)
    {
    printf("Your guess was to low \n");
    low = computerGuess+1;
    }
  else if (numberGuess < computerGuess)
    {
    printf("Your guess was to high \n");
    high = computerGuess-1;
}
  else if (numberGuess == computerGuess)
{
printf("Yess!! you got it!\n");
    }
 }

return 0; 
}
```